# Xamarin Amazon IAP error using D8+R8 with Proguard in Release Failing but working Debug

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, proguard

I am using AmazonIapV2Android.dll provided by Amazon team for the Xamarin.Android project. I have implemented it last year and have been using successfully with Dx+proguard with using proguard rules as below. Those lines are also suggested by Amazon documentation. see the [link](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/in-app-purchasing/iap-obfuscate-the-code.html)

```
-dontwarn com.amazon.**
-keep class com.amazon.** {*;} 
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

Recently I have changed my xamarin.android project using d8+r8 using the same proguard file. Everything, google iap implementation also fine but Amazon IAP started throwing exception.

> Jsonable.CheckForErrors
> (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] jsonMap)
> com.amazon.device.iap.cpt.AmazonException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> Missing type parameter.
>
> at com.amazon.device.iap.cpt.RequestOutput.CreateFromJson
> (System.String jsonMessage) [0x0002d] in
> <26520843ea114e5a91256077e0412906>:0 \n  at
> com.amazon.device.iap.cpt.AmazonIapV2Impl+AmazonIapV2Base.GetProductData
> (com.amazon.device.iap.cpt.SkusInput skusInput) [0x00013] in

I am using also linker as User and sdk assemblies, this is triggering obfuscation obviously and some methods are removed by the linker because using Sdk assemblies only or No Linking, everything works fine.
I have added the `AmazonIapV2Android` as linker to skip but it didnt help.

When I check the code implementation of the RequestOutput.CreateFromJson function implementation, it looks like as below.

```
using com.amazon.device.iap.cpt.json;

    namespace com.amazon.device.iap.cpt
    {
        public sealed class RequestOutput : Jsonable
        {
            public string RequestId{get;set;}        
           
            public static RequestOutput CreateFromJson(string jsonMessage)
            {
                try 
                {
                    Dictionary<string, object> jsonMap = Json.Deserialize(jsonMessage) as Dictionary<string, object>;
                    Jsonable.CheckForErrors(jsonMap);
                    return CreateFromDictionary(jsonMap);
                }
                catch(System.ApplicationException ex)
                {
                    throw new AmazonException("Error encountered while UnJsoning", ex);
                }
            }
```

and implementation for Jsonable in the dll looks as below

```
namespace com.amazon.device.iap.cpt 
{
    public abstract class Jsonable 
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, object> unrollObjectIntoMap<T>(Dictionary<string, T> obj) where T:Jsonable  
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> jsonableDict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (var entry in obj) 
            {
                jsonableDict.Add (entry.Key, ((Jsonable)entry.Value).GetObjectDictionary());
            }
            return jsonableDict;
        }

        public static List<object> unrollObjectIntoList<T>(List<T> obj) where T:Jsonable
        {
            List<object> jsonableList = new List<object>();
            foreach (Jsonable entry in obj) 
            {
                jsonableList.Add(entry.GetObjectDictionary());
            }
            return jsonableList;
        }

        public abstract Dictionary<string, object> GetObjectDictionary();
        
        public static void CheckForErrors(Dictionary<string, object> jsonMap)
        {
            object error;
            if (jsonMap.TryGetValue("error", out error))
            {
                throw new AmazonException(error as string);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

I have tried to use linker.xml with settings like below also but it didnt help either.

```
<assembly fullname="AmazonIapV2Android">
    <namespace fullname="com.amazon.device.iap.cpt" />
    <namespace fullname="com.amazon.device.iap.cpt.log" />
    <namespace fullname="com.amazon.device.iap.cpt.json" />
</assembly>
```

I cannot figure out why should throw exception while i am defining keepclass for all methods and members under the namespace starting with `com.amazon`  prefix.
Any idea what could be the reason here?

EDIT: just had several more tests and my initiale comment was slightly wrong. strange way app is working in debug with Linker set "SDK assemblies only" but in release it doesnt work even with "SDK assemblies only"

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this is a known problem for using R8 and Amazon IAP. Typical amazon doesnt care and update their package. especially there is no update for Xamarin IAP since 2016.
Here are the links to problem
https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/205480/in-app-billing-not-working-since-android-studio-de.html

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134766810

Currently there are 3 workarounds,

1. disable r8. Bad is that no obfuscation, no optimization.
2. Use dx+proguard+multi dex instead of d8+r8. There is a problem here if you use androidx, androidx libraries dont work with dx+proguard, they work only with d8+r8, you need to go back to support libraries.
3. I am not sure but amazon [website](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/in-app-purchasing/iap-obfuscate-the-code.html) claims that it is claimed, it works with r8 but this is pobably for the android java library not for xamarin. Because as i cheked there is newer version to as jar. You can theoretically use Binding library to get a new dll and try but I read even for Android studio projects, this doesnt work. So i tried to create a binding library and it had many errors and api seems to be different than xamarin. It is a lot of effort for non-profitable app store.
   here is the link to github [issue](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/5466) on xamarin.android as well.